# Read/write to a file using AutoCloseable and objects for writing using Java

Tags: java, io

I am currently writing a small configuration API for myself, i want to use it to easily read/write to a file, however, i want to make sure it's efficient and get some other options into the field of my programming. How can i make my classes even more efficient?

This is the class for the options for comments, headers and such

```
package config.options;

public class ConfigOptions {

/**
 * This is pretty much it for now.
 */

private boolean appendable = false;
private boolean encryptable = false;
private char separator = '=';
private String header = "[%header%]";
private String ignoreLine = "#";


public boolean isEncryptable() {
    return encryptable;
}


public void setEncryptable(boolean encryptable) {
    this.encryptable = encryptable;
}


public char getSeparator() {
    return separator;
}


public void setSeparator(char separator) {
    this.separator = separator;
}


public boolean isAppendable() {
    return appendable;
}


public void setAppendable(boolean appendable) {
    this.appendable = appendable;
}


public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}


public void setHeader(String header) {
    this.header = header;
}


public String getIgnoreLine() {
    return ignoreLine;
}


public void setIgnoreLine(String ignoreLine) {
    this.ignoreLine = ignoreLine;
}

}
```

This is my class for writing to the file

```
package config.write;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import config.options.ConfigOptions;

public class ConfigWriter {

File file;
BufferedWriter writer;
private String URL;
private ConfigOptions options;


public ConfigWriter(String URL, ConfigOptions options, String filename) {
    this.URL = URL;
    this.options = options;

    File dir = new File(URL);
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    file = new File(dir, filename);
    if(!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, options.isAppendable()))) {
        this.writer = writer;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void writeAll(String[] configobjects, String[] values) {
    if(file.exists() && file.canWrite()) {
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < configobjects.length; i++) {
                writer.write(configobjects[i] + options.getSeparator() + values[i]);
            }
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void writeType(String configobject, Object value)  {

    if(file.exists() && file.canWrite()) {
        try {
            writer.write(configobject + options.getSeparator() + String.valueOf(value));
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getCause());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot write to the file, either it does not exist, or you cannot write to it.");
    }
}


public boolean setType(String stringobject, Object newvalue) {

    return false;
}

public boolean remove(String stringobject) {

    return false;
}   



public String getURL() {
    return URL;
}

public void setURL(String uRL) {
    URL = uRL;
}   

}
```

This is my class for reading from the file.

```
package config.read;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import config.options.ConfigOptions;

public class ConfigReader implements ConfigReadingRequirements {

File file;
BufferedReader reader;
private boolean readable;
private ConfigOptions options;

public ConfigReader(String URL, ConfigOptions options) {
    file = new File(URL);

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        this.reader = reader;
        if (!file.canRead()) {
            this.readable = false;
            System.out.println("Cannot read the file, are you sure you have the correct URL?");
        } else {
            this.readable = true;
            this.options = options;
        }

        if (options.getSeparator() == -1) {
            options.setSeparator('=');
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String[] readAll() {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            if (!reader.readLine().startsWith("#")) {
                data.add(reader.readLine());
            }
        }
        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
            String[] dat = new String[data.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                dat[i] = data.get(i);
            }
            return dat;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public Object readType(String configobject) {
    if (isReadable()) {
        String str;
        try {
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!str.startsWith(options.getIgnoreLine())) {
                    if (str.split(String.valueOf(options.getSeparator()))[0].equalsIgnoreCase(configobject)) {
                        str = splitToMatch(str);
                        return String.valueOf(str);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getCause());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        System.out.println("Cannot read the file, are you sure you have the correct URL?");
    }
    return null;
}

private String splitToMatch(String splittable) {
    return String.valueOf(splittable.split(String.valueOf(options.getSeparator()))[1]);
}

public boolean isReadable() {
    return readable;
}

public BufferedReader getReader() {
    return reader;
}

public void setReader(BufferedReader reader) {
    this.reader = reader;
}

}
```

The interfaces they implement are simply methods that every class needs to have, like the writer needs a writeType method which has an object as argument, a way to remove text from the file and a way to change the value of a key.

For the reader it's simply a readType that returns an object.

How can i improve my code? What would you suggest?

Comment: If you don't do this for educational purpose (and are willing to skip the header), just use [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably make your `ConfigOptions` class serializeable, just in case.

Comment: Thank you for your input, i'll be sure to read about it and implement it